# Facebook Spring Social authentication missing "state" parameter in demand

Tags: java, facebook, spring-boot, spring-social

This may seem like a question already made but the structure I use is different from the cases already discussed on this forum.
I'm using an example application for Spring Social with Spring Boot.
I created my app on Facebook and placed clientId and secret in the Spring application. Then I made a small castomization by creating the SocialConfig class with a Bean connectController to customize the callback.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableSocial;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;

@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {

        ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);

            connectController.setApplicationUrl("http://......");

            return connectController;
    }  
}
```

Up here everything ok. The problem is that facebook answers me by adding the "state" parameter that misleads the application.
I have documented this parameter and I understand that it should be inserted into the call I make to the social. Only I can not understand how to do it and I did not find directions on the internet. Can someone help me?